# Using one DECLARE statement for several variables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, declare

Is there any difference using one [DECLARE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) statement for declaring all your variables in store procedure or function instead of using the statement for each one.

For example:

```
DECLARE @INST1 INT 
       ,@INST2 BIGINT
       ,@INST3 DATETIME
       .......
       ,@INSTN INT
```

and

```
DECLARE @INST1 INT
DECLARE @INST2 BIGINT
DECLARE @INST3 DATETIME
..................
DECLARE @INSTN INT
```

I am asking for differences like performance, reducing SQL server caches size and other internal for the server stuff, that I am not familiar with and can make the server job easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IHMO, there's no difference because the engine instantiate the same memory about variables in either cases. Is only a short ay to write code, but I prefer using a DECLARE for each variable because the code becomes read better

Comment: As long as you format your code neatly, then the readability shouldn't become an issue.

Comment: Yes, but I'm glad to have indipendent rows, because to reduce offset of use of a variable, I like define my variabile in the neborough of I use it.